# Need some advice on DynamoDb Tables schema

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, schema

I am building a review site.
It will review hotels, restaurants and cafes (lets call them listings),
so there will be three categories of listings.
Each of these listings will have reviews.

Now end users will be able to like / dislike the listing or individual reviews.
I am using AWS Amplify to build this site.

The way the front end will query the data would as follows.

1. A search box may want to see restaurants in a given location say Sydney / London etc.
2. when the list of restaurants has come up, the end user can click on each restaurant to see the reviews for this restaurant.
3. The end user can like / dislike the restaurant or do the same like / dislike for individual reviews.

I am new to NoSQL Database concepts, so need some advice on how this should be structured. Below image shows what I have in mind.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoSQL schema modeling should performed based on the access patterns of the data. Based on the access patterns you provided

1. Restaurants for a given location can be searched the Listing
   Secondary Partition and in addition to that you can also sort them
   using the listing rating.
2. For each restaurant you can get the
   reviews associated with that. Are you storing the original review
   blobs here? If so be cautioned about the maximum row size and
   consider compressing the review or use S3 to store the original
   review.
3. Incrementing the columns for Review_Likes and Dislikes
   would solve your use case 3.

However, to completely validate your schema I need the following information. In Listing table the Primary Partition key - Category values are in very small number (Hotel, Cafe, Restaurant, etc.) and this can cause hot partitions. DynamoDB expects the primary keys to be [uniformly distributed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-uniform-load.html) for optimal performance.

Comment: Thanks Aditya. 
> Are you storing the original review blobs here? Yes I was thinking of doing that. I will probably store it in S3, have been reading similar recommendation on various forums. 
> Partition key - Category values are in very small number 
This will grow over time as I add more categories, but for the first few months(6), I will only be focusing on these three. If that is the case, would you have another recommendation?

Thanks

Comment: Storing in S3 can be an option, however check for S3 latencies and your API latency requirements as getting data from S3 can be > 1 second. One Quick Question regarding your Query1 : If you want to get the list of restaurants in a city your query might have to filter out for restaurants as your secondary partition and sort key does not have it. You can also consider creating a composite secondary key (category_type | rating) which can avoid filtering and it reduces your read IOPS. Limited set of categories should not cause you a problem.

Comment: > You can also consider creating a composite secondary key (category_type | rating) which can avoid filtering and it reduces your read IOPS --- thanks Aditya, this makes sense. I am currently building some boilerplate apps to make all the components work, DB setup should be later today, I will get back to you with how I go.